Turn off auto-formatting in Markdown
In Markdown mode, I often write blog posts for my Jekyll blog that involve inline LaTeX (or probably it's MathJax). If I use underscores it confuses the buffer and it starts "previewing" italicized text in areas which shouldn't be italicized, and (correctly) aren't when the markdown is rendered.
Something else happens which I think is part of the same feature: it thinks it should "preview" something where spaces are shown as underscores. Not sure why or precisely when it thinks to do this.
I'm happy to just turn the feature off that previews the formatting in the buffer. How can I do this?
I'm also interested in the same question for org mode, where I get similar problems.

The question is unclear. You don't say what you mean by "auto-formatting" or what causes it. Do you see the same problem if you start Emacs using emacs -Q (no init file)? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

@Drew What I mean is the display ("preview"?) in the buffer, so that text that it italicized upon rendering is displayed as italic in the actual buffer. And I'm assuming the superfluous underlines are similar.

Please add all clarifying info to the question itself. Comments can be deleted at any time. Questions need to stand on their own. Thx.

I believe what you are talking about is the result of font-lock-mode: if you turn it off with M-: (font-lock-mode -1), they should go away,  but so will a lot of other nice things (like colors). You can turn it back on by calling the same function with argument 1. Maybe you can try the experiment and update your question with the results.

For Org mode, you can turn it off (along with other emphasis indications: bold, underline, italic), by customizing org-fontify-emphasized-text to nil. I don't know anything about Markdown mode.

@Eric, when underscores are used in math expressions, you should start math mode insertion, LaTeX rule, with math delimiters $..$, $$..$$, \[..\], otherwise italics is the rendering mode. Same when in org mode.

One more thing: check your markdown configuration if you have the following: (setq markdown-enable-math t)  and (setq markdown-enable-html t).
